# Bigtreetech upload stalled after uncommented REPRAP_DISCOUNT_FULL_GRAPHIC_SMART_CONTROLLER

Tags: marlin, skr-v1.3, full-graphic-smart-controller, bigtreetech

I recently bought a BigTreeTech SKR V1.3 and uncommented `REPRAP_DISCOUNT_FULL_GRAPHIC_SMART_CONTROLLER` and clicked the upload button but faced an error that says:

```
Marlin\src\lcd\ultralcd.cpp:767:9: error: 'touch_buttons' was not declared in this scope
if (touch_buttons) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
Marlin\src\lcd\ultralcd.cpp:767:9: note: suggested alternative: 'buttons'
if (touch_buttons) {

^~~~~~~~~~~~~
buttons
Marlin\src\lcd\ultralcd.cpp:805:5: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
else wait_for_unclick = false;
^~~~
*** [.pio\build\LPC1768\src\src\lcd\ultralcd.cpp.o] Error 1
```

I am not sure what above message means, but can anyone else shed some light on why I am receiving these errors?

FWIW, I am using Marlin 2.

Answer (score 2):

There is a temporary solution which I have found here, on the reprap forums, [Re: Upload to the board failed after LCD enabled](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?13,857852,857876#msg-857876):

> An official fix has been posted. Grab the new ultralcd.cpp from [[github.com](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/bugfix-2.0.x/Marlin/src/lcd/ultralcd.cpp)]

Apparently the sources contained a bug which was fixed later, a new version download fixed the problem.

Comment: I realize this is "your" own answer, however, rules still apply to answering your own question. As it stands right now, it can only be construed as a "link only" answer, which would make it ripe for deletion. Please post the gist of the information here in the question and use the link as reference. The reason why we ask this is because links can become stale ... if you bring the information here, it's here for perpetuity.

Comment: So what is the actual solution? The link is just to another question... As Paulster2 states, please edit your answer and include the solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Marlin 2.0.0 is in an ***Alpha*** state.](http://marlinfw.org/meta/download/) 'Alpha' is a state before *Beta*, meaning, it's not hot off the presses, it isn't even *off the presses*. You need to go back to the most recent "stable" version of Marlin, which is 1.1.9 (found on the same page as the link above). This should *most likely* solve the errors and problems you're seeing.

Comment: Marlin 1.1.9. is not compatible with 32-bit boards like the SKR 1.3.
In my personal opinion, there's no reason to use 1.1.9 for any printer these days.

Answer (score 1):

Marlin 2.0 is still very much in development.

If you face issues like this and you're certain you haven't introduced any typos,
try downloading the most current version of Marlin again ([Github](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/tree/bugfix-2.0.x) -> Download -> Download zip).
Copy in your configuration files and try to compile.

If the issue persists, you may try to use a version from a few days / weeks ago.
For this, select a previous commit from this [list](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/commits/bugfix-2.0.x), and press the `<>` button to activate it.